# Sinónimo de "Ya que"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, sinónimos, locuciones

¿De qué otra forma puedo decir... ***Ya que** me siento triste*?  o  ***Ya que** se ha comprobado...*

No quiero seguir repitiendo el **YA QUE** en un informe.

Comment: Puedes usar *dado que.*

Answer (score 11):

- **Dado que** me siento triste...
- **Debido a que** me siento triste...
- **Ahora que** me siento triste...
- **Porque** me siento triste...
- **Como** me siento triste...
- **Con motivo de que** me siento triste...
- **[Considerando que](https://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/582871082182557696)** me siento triste...
- **[En vista de que](http://www.sinonimosonline.com/puesto-que/)** me siento triste..
- **[Visto que](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bw2em88)** estoy triste...
- **[Puesto que](http://www.sinonimosonline.com/puesto-que/)** me siento triste...
- **[A causa de que](http://educacion.ufm.edu/a-consecuencia-como-consecuencia-2/)** estoy triste...
- **[Como consecuencia de que](http://educacion.ufm.edu/a-consecuencia-como-consecuencia-2/)** estoy triste... <sub>[Fundéu](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/a-consecuencia-de-2309/) no está del todo de acuerdo y recomienda la preposición 'a' (en algún momento lo volveré pregunta)</sub>
- **Siendo que** estoy triste... <sub>muy usada pero [la RAE no lo recomienda mucho](https://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/582871082182557696)</sub>

Comment: ¿La cuarta no debería ser "**porque** me siento triste"?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo. Tuve la duda y lo consulté. Creo que lo explica el numeral (d) de este enlace. http://www.rae.es/consultas/porque-porque-por-que-por-que Lo entendí bien?....o es el caso (c).?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo. Cambié de opinión. Creo que tienes razón.

Comment: En el numeral (c) está el ejemplo tal como lo necesitamos reemplazando _ya que_ .  **No fui a la fiesta porque no tenía ganas [= ya que no tenía ganas]**. En este caso **Porque me siento triste** no voy a la fiesta